# Default (integer) user input in while loop in Python

Tags: python, integer

How can i set a default integer (for example 2) in below code:

```
def inputNumber(message):
  while True:
    try:
       userInput = int(input(message))       
    except ValueError:
       print("Not an integer! Try again.")
       continue
    else:
       return userInput 
       break 
 
#specify_number = inputNumber("Specify number: ")
specify_number = inputNumber("Specify number: " or "2")
```

Comment: This is unclear. Please elaborate. It is easy enough to test if an empty string is returned by `input()` and then have your code return the default value in that case, but you seem to want something more.

Comment: Under what circumstance should the default be returned? Right now you're prompting until you get a legal integer response, which makes sense (although you can remove `else:` (or `continue`) and `break`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
def input_number(message, default = None):
    if default is not None:
        message = message + f' (or press enter for {default})'
    while True:
        user_input = input(message)
        if len(user_input) == 0:
            return default
        else:
            try:
                return int(user_input)
            except ValueError:
               print("Not an integer! Try again.")
```

Used like

```
n = input_number("Enter a number:",2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a default value to input:

Replace:

```
userInput = int(input(message))
```

By:

```
userInput = input(message) or "2"
userInput = int(userInput)
```